# How to get input from fingerprint scanner and save it

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

I am Using Android Marshmallow, and Moto G4 plus a device for testing.

I want to create an application which will take the fingerprint input and saved in a local database(sqlite) Or to database, I mean which type we can take input and save it?

Comment: @justchill use android Fingerprint API, available on Internet..

Comment: @justchill https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog follow this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to store fingerprint data along with username, image, email etc in database in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813525/how-to-store-fingerprint-data-along-with-username-image-email-etc-in-database)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't get fingerprint template or image from android Fingerprint API.
Fingerprint data are stored in a secure place by android system and are not accessible.

But you can ask the system to authenticate the user.

Here [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog)

The doc, in section [Fingerprint Authentication](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html)

Comment: Is there any way to get finger print and store in database ?  or any SDK available for same purpose ?

Comment: @Kels Just save as base64 so you never have to worry about saving.

Comment: There is no logic here, because fingerprint id is the same as face id. But you CAN read raw data from camera, including face.

Comment: what if we want to use this finger scanner of android instead of external finger scanner any suggestion for it ?

Answer (score 12):

1. In technical terms,
   Android OS stores Fingerprints in **TEE (stands for Trusted Execution Environment)**, TEE is separate and isolated area in phone's hardware or software depending on the way device is manufactured. TEE will never let us in even if device is rooted. [Check this for more details about Trusty OS](https://source.android.com/security/trusty/)
2. If your requirement is to get fingerprint signature *(which is a critical practice from user's privacy point of view)* you'll have to buy a 3rd party fingerprint scanner and integrate with your app.

Comment: If you've copy-pasted that from somewhere (I couldn't find a source at least), adding quotes needs to be done in combination with adding the source. Otherwise, this would be plagiarism. See [the referencing guide](/help/referencing). You don't appear to have copied this from anywhere, so please don't abuse the quote formatting.

Comment: True, I havent copied it.. just a formatting issue.

Answer (score 7):

Although you can't get the fingerprint data from Android's Fingerprint API, you can get it using an external fingerprint scanner which often comes with its own SDK, just check with the manufacturer.

Comment: Do you know any option?

Comment: @RenanBandeira FS80 from Futronic. They provide a android sdk for such model. In my opnion, FS80 is a bit bigger, but, there are others models in market that also provide SDKs for android integration.