# How to add Fingerprints programmatically

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to add fingerprint of 60 - 100 students.
Then use it to mark their attendance by scanning their fingerprint daily when they enter the class.

Is it possible to add fingerprints programmatically?
Its ok if it goes to the settings page; but I need the fingerprints data to store in my server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160643/how-to-get-fingerprint-input-from-user-and-save-to-sqlite-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Fingerprint input from user and save to sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160643/how-to-get-fingerprint-input-from-user-and-save-to-sqlite-in-android)